# Python - modify vs. overwrite an object reference

Tags: python, object-reference

Can someone explain modifying vs. overwriting object reference in an easy to understand way? Here is an example of what I mean:

By modifying an object reference:

```
nested_list = [[]]*3
nested

result:
[[], [], []]
# now let me **modify** the object reference
nested[1].append('zzz')

result:
[['zzz'], ['zzz'], ['zzz']]
```

By overwriting an object reference:

```
nested_list = [[]]*3
nested

result:
[[], [], []]
# now let me **modify** the object reference
nested[1] = ['zzz']

result:
[[], ['zzz'], []]
```

Does that mean when using "append" we are only modifying the object reference while using assigning values i.e.

```
nested[1] = ['zzz']
```

we are overwriting the value and assigning nested[1] to a new object reference? Is it caused by the underlying difference between the "append" method and assigning values? If so what's the difference?

Comment: You're assigning to `nested_list`, but then printing `nested`. How are these related?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: The `*` operator on `list`s copies the references inside it. So there are three references to the same (empty) mutable list, inside the outer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assign the name `x` to an empty list such that it is easier to reason about the code.

In your first example

```
>>> x = []
>>> nested = [x]*3
>>> nested
[[], [], []]
```

you are creating a list `nested` with three references to `x`. Here's proof:

```
>>> all(e is x for e in nested)
True
```

We only ever created one empty list `x`, that's why

```
nested[0].append('zzz')
nested[1].append('zzz')
nested[2].append('zzz')
```

and

```
x.append('zzz')
```

are all equivalent and appending *to the same list in memory*:

```
>>> nested[0].append('zzz')
>>> nested
[['zzz'], ['zzz'], ['zzz']]
>>> nested[1].append('zzz')
>>> nested
[['zzz', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'zzz']]
>>> nested[2].append('zzz')
>>> nested
[['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz']]
>>> x.append('zzz')
>>> nested
[['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz'], ['zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz', 'zzz']]
```

The second example is easy. You create a list `nested` which initially holds three references to the same empty list.

Then you *overwrite* what the second element of `nested` (i.e. `nested[1]`) refers to by issuesing

```
>>> x = []
>>> nested = [x]*3
>>> nested[1] = ['zzz']
>>> nested
[[], ['zzz'], []]
```

The second element of `nested` is a new list that has nothing to do with the first and third element of `nested`.

```
>>> nested[0] is nested[1]
False
>>> nested[2] is nested[1]
False
>>> nested[0] is nested[2]
True
```

Since you did not modify what `nested[0]` and `nested[2]` reference, they are still holding the same empty list (which in our example also goes by the name `x`).

```
>>> x.append('x')
>>> nested
[['x'], ['zzz'], ['x']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But why does "appending" data to list change them all while assigning values overwrite one of the list instead of all?

Comment: @thatMeow Hmm, I thought I made that crystal clear. Maybe read the answer again? You initially have a list `nested` which holds references **to the same empty list `x` in memory**. When you mutate `x` by appending to it, of course every reference to `x` in `nested` is going to see that change. There are only ever two lists in this case. `x` and `nested`. No more. In the second example, you do not mutate `x`. You create a **new** list `['zzz']` and then say that `nested[1]` must point to that new list. `nested[0]` and `nested[2]` still point to `x`.

Comment: Ah got it, putting it this way make it easier for me to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, the `*` operator on `list`s just copies the references inside the list:

```
nested_list = [[]] * 3
```

All three elements inside `nested_list` refer to the same list. This makes sense if you think about what the expression above really says. The evaluation really happen in the following order:

```
nested_list = [[]]  # first create a list with an empty list.
nested_list = nested_list * 3  # duplicate the references to that empty list
```

To the second part of your question. If you replace the second element by a new list:

```
nested_list[1] = ['zzz']
```

The first and third element are referring to the same empty list, but the one just assigned to (`['zzz']`) is a new list (with one element, `'zzz'`.)

E.g. if you do the following you will see that the first and third are still referring to the same list:

```
nested_list[0].append('a')
print(nested_list)
# [['a'], ['zzz'], ['a']]
```

## Solution

To create three distinct empty lists, which is probably what you want, you usually do something like (the following lines are equivalent):

```
nested_lists = [[] for _ in range(3)]
nested_lists = [[], [], []]
```

Comment: can you explain `[[] for _ in range(3)]` ? How is the `for` loop used here ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Sure. It is called a list comprehension. Check this link: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions . Does that answer your question?

Comment: Understood the list comprehension concept